# Avoid Circular Dependancy: MySQL/Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, circular-dependency

We're having trouble dealing with a circular dependancy and wondered if anyone could suggest a solution. If we want to delete a client, entity framework refuses to do this because it tells us a foreign key constraint fails. Our tables are setup like this:

**ClientAccounts**

```
Id [PK]
Forenames
Surname
DefaultEmailId [FK, NULLABLE]
```

**ClientEmailAddresses**

```
Id [PK]
Description
EmailAddress
ClientId [FK, NON-NULLABLE]
```

So a **Client** can have **zero or many email addresses** associated with their account. One of which will be their default contact email address.

I recognise that if we allowed the ClientEmailAddresses table to have a null ClientId, it would work ok; but we don't want a situation where we could have orphan email records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to store field 'default' in table ClientEmailAddresses and remove DefaultEmailId from table ClientAccounts. I don't know your code structure but sometimes  structure like yours is redundant.

Comment: We like this solution as it will break the circular issue, but the worry is that we can then have multiple defaults..

Comment: Yes, in this case your logic will be more complicated. You should at first reset previous default status and set a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you first delete the entries in **ClientEmailAddresses** ?

Imagine a stored procedure like this :

```
##  delete Client
delete from ClientEmailAddresses where ClientId = ID2delete
delete from ClientAccounts where Id = ID2delete
```

where Id2delete is the client ID to delete.

I haven't try, but should work !